# Create a DynamicMap in Holoviews that responds to both a RadioButton and a tap

Tags: python, holoviews

Consider the following code that creates a Points plot that changes which DataFrame it is plotting based on a RadioButton.

```
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

df_a = pd.DataFrame(index = ['a','b', 'c', 'd'], data = {'x':range(4), 'y':range(4)})
df_b = pd.DataFrame(index = ['w','x', 'y', 'z'], data = {'x':range(4), 'y':range(3,-1,-1)})

radio_button = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(options=['df_a', 'df_b'])
@pn.depends(option = radio_button.param.value)
def update_plot(option):
    if option == 'df_a':
        points = hv.Points(data=df_a, kdims=['x', 'y'])
    if option == 'df_b':
        points = hv.Points(data=df_b, kdims=['x', 'y'])
    points = points.opts(size = 10, tools = ['tap'])
    
    return points

pn.Column(radio_button, hv.DynamicMap(update_plot))
```

What I would like to add is functionality where when one of the points is tapped, a table to the right is filled in with location information from the corresponding DataFrame (i.e. if the lower left point is tapped when `df_a` is selected, the data at `df_a.loc['a']` should be printed in a table.

I’ve tried a few things, but I can’t find a good way that 1) Updates the table on new clicks and 2) doesn’t reset the zoom level whenever the RadioButton selection is switched.

Number 2 is particularly important for my actual purpose (this is an extremely stripped down version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a complicated question,** mostly because holoviews is a more advanced library, but after a bunch of digging, I figured it out.

---

**We've got three main objects in our program.**

1. A `Points` graph.
2. A `RadioButtonGroup` selector.
3. A `Table` view.

Both the `Points` and the `Table` views are to update dynamically based on the `RadioButtonGroup`, and the `Table` view is also going to update based on the selected `Point`.

---

So, we're going to need two `Stream` objects. One, a `Selection1D()`, so we know when a `Point` is selected. Two, a custom Stream based on the `RadioButtonGroup`. But we'll get to that in a second.

---

We've got your imports...

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import streams
import panel as pn
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import RadioButtonGroup
hv.extension('bokeh')
```

And your given data.

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(index = ['a','b', 'c', 'd'], data = {'x':range(4), 'y':range(4)})
df_b = pd.DataFrame(index = ['w','x', 'y', 'z'], data = {'x':range(4), 'y':range(3,-1,-1)})
```

Also, for convenience, let's make a dictionary based on the names, so we can easily reference the data from the `RadioButtonGroup`. And I'll make a variable to keep track of the current `DataFrame`

```
dfs = {'df_a': df_a, 'df_b': df_b}
current_df = df_a #this will change
```

Here's where we define our `DynamicMaps` and the `RadioButtonGroup`. `Stream`s included too. I added some comments so it is more clear.

```
radio_button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=['df_a', 'df_b'], active=0)

#STREAMS HERE. VERY IMPORTANT
selection_stream = streams.Selection1D() #updates when Point selected
selected_df = streams.Stream.define('selected_df', df=current_df) #updates when RadioButtonGroup selection changes.

def radio_button_callback(attr, old, new): #attr not used. old is previous value of radio_button
    global current_df
    current_df = dfs[list(dfs.keys())[new]] #set current_df
    dynamic_map.event(df=current_df) #these events update the map and table.
    dynamic_table.event(df=current_df)
    selection_stream.source = dynamic_map

radio_button_group.on_change("active", radio_button_callback) #trigger for callback

#keywords must be called index and df.
def update_table(index=current_df.index, df=current_df):
    if index == []: #this happens when the plot is clicked but no Point is selected.
        index = [x for x in range(len(current_df.index))]
    selected_df = current_df.iloc[index]
    return hv.Table(selected_df)

def update_plot(index=0, df=current_df):
    points = hv.Points(data=df)
    return points.opts(size = 10, tools = ['tap'])

dynamic_map = hv.DynamicMap(update_plot, streams=[selection_stream, selected_df()])
dynamic_table = hv.DynamicMap(update_table, streams=[selection_stream, selected_df()])
```

And finally, add your `Panel` formatting.

```
column_layout = pn.Column(radio_button_group, dynamic_map)
row_layout = pn.Row(dynamic_table, column_layout)
```

Final Result: [Streamable Link](https://streamable.com/r3xti8)

Please let me know if this is not the intended result, or if I am missing something important. Also, I forgot to record this, but the `DynamicMap` keeps the scale of the `Points` graph the same, even if you change the `DataFrame`, fulfilling your second requirement.

**Hope this helped!**

--

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

To have a dynamically updating title, the easiest method is to probably define another variable `current_df_index` (set it to 0 of course).

Then, in the method `radio_button_callback`, add `current_df_index` to the global variables, and set it to `new`.

```
current_df_index = new
```

Finally, in the `update_table` method, let's change the return statement to a variable instead, assign the title, and then return.

```
table = hv.Table(selected_df)
table.opts(title=list(dfs.keys())[current_df_index])
return table
```

--

Here is the full updated code.

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import streams
import panel as pn
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import RadioButtonGroup
hv.extension('bokeh')

df_a = pd.DataFrame(index = ['a','b', 'c', 'd'], data = {'x':range(4), 'y':range(4)})
df_b = pd.DataFrame(index = ['w','x', 'y', 'z'], data = {'x':range(4), 'y':range(3,-1,-1)})

dfs = {'df_a': df_a, 'df_b': df_b}
current_df = df_a #this will change
current_df_index = 0

radio_button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=['df_a', 'df_b'], active=0)

#STREAMS HERE. VERY IMPORTANT
selection_stream = streams.Selection1D() #updates when Point selected
selected_df = streams.Stream.define('selected_df', df=current_df) #updates when RadioButtonGroup selection changes.

def radio_button_callback(attr, old, new): #attr not used. old is previous value of radio_button
    global current_df, current_df_index
    current_df = dfs[list(dfs.keys())[new]] #set current_df
    current_df_index = new
    dynamic_map.event(df=current_df) #these events update the map and table.
    dynamic_table.event(df=current_df)
    selection_stream.source = dynamic_map

radio_button_group.on_change("active", radio_button_callback) #trigger for callback

#keywords must be called index and df.
def update_table(index=current_df.index, df=current_df):
    if index == []: #this happens when the plot is clicked but no Point is selected.
        index = [x for x in range(len(current_df.index))]
    selected_df = current_df.iloc[index]
    table = hv.Table(selected_df)
    table.opts(title=list(dfs.keys())[current_df_index])
    return table

def update_plot(index=0, df=current_df):
    points = hv.Points(data=df)
    return points.opts(size = 10, tools = ['tap'])

dynamic_map = hv.DynamicMap(update_plot, streams=[selection_stream, selected_df()])
dynamic_table = hv.DynamicMap(update_table, streams=[selection_stream, selected_df()])

column_layout = pn.Column(radio_button_group, dynamic_map)
row_layout = pn.Row(dynamic_table, column_layout)
```

Comment: This has been super helpful!! One question though - can you figure out a way I can get the title of the table to switch between "df_a" and "df_b", depending on what radio button is selected? The title can be set with `.opts(title = ...)`, and I've tried a few ideas, but I can't seem to get anything that updates properly...

Comment: @hm8 Updated the answer. Hope it is what you are looking for.